# Is non-max suppression done on GPU on Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

```
tf.image.non_max_suppression
```

Tensorflow provide this method for non-max suppression, I wonder does tensorflow provide GPU support for it?

Comment: No. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7511

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**. If you try:

```
boxes = np.random.uniform(size=(100, 4))
scores = np.random.uniform(size=(100,))

bx = tf.constant(boxes, dtype=tf.float32)
sc = tf.constant(scores, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.device("gpu:0"):
    indx = tf.image.non_max_suppression(bx, sc, 1000)
```

you will see:

```
    NotFoundError: No registered 'NonMaxSuppressionV3' OpKernel for GPU devices compatible with node {{node NonMaxSuppressionV3}} = NonMaxSuppressionV3[T=DT_FLOAT](dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input)
    .  Registered:  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
 [Op:NonMaxSuppressionV3]
```

Comment: Note: this was true at the time this answer was posted, but a GPU implementation was added soon after (May 2019): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/2269de23048d4d98a26368deeeae29c0abca2b3f.

Comment: BTW, the current CUDA implementation is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/image/non_max_suppression_op.cu.cc#L605